# lvmetad and kernel 4.13.0-25 problem

Tags: boot, kernel

Just upgraded to kernel 4.13.0-25, and on reboot this morning received the 'failed to connect to lvmetad' error message, then the computer attempted again and again and again, failing each time to connect.

I rebooted, used Shift to get to the grub menu, and chose the previous kernel (4.13.0-21). The computer booted fine.

Any idea what's up with -25? Especially since -21 boots with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 4.13.0.25 has been superseded by 4.13.0.26

See [Canonical fixes Ubuntu 16.04 LTS regression causing boot failure on some PCs](http://canonical-fixes-ubuntu-16-04-lts-regression-causing-boot-failure-on-some)

Please boot using an older kernel and update your system again.

Hope this helps

Comment: awesome! thanks! I had pinned the previous kernel in grub, didn't see the update.